# Appending and Prepending '#' in an string using only Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I am new to regex and recently faced this problem

> Appending and Prepending '#' in an string using only Regex

In this suppose we have string such as `Hello my name is #First Name# @EducationDetail@`

Now I have to append and prepend `#` in this using only regular expression so it will become

`#Hello my name is #First Name# @EducationDetail@#`

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me nobody ever actually used this as an interview question.

Comment: @Carson63000 One our client asked my colleague this question to him before development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var res = Regex.Replace(input, @"^(.*)$", "#$1#");`

Comment: "using only regular expression"

Comment: Hm, when tried `$1` it did not work for me - so used delegate instead :-S Definitely it is better but it is a test task ;-) (though it is pointless, indeed) +1

Comment: @zerkms, 1st variant removed ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as polishchuk, but a bit less verbose

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, ".+", "#$0#");
```

Since regular expressions are greedy by default, `.+` will capture the entire string. `$0` captures the entire match, so there's no reason to use an explicit capture in this case.